# Aggregate and Weighted Mean in R

Tags: r, aggregate

I'm trying to calculate asset-weighted returns by asset class. For the life of me, I can't figure out how to do it using the aggregate command.

My data frame looks like this

```
dat <- data.frame(company, fundname, assetclass, return, assets)
```

I'm trying to do something like (don't copy this, it's wrong):

```
aggregate(dat, list(dat$assetclass), weighted.mean, w=(dat$return, dat$assets))
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For starters, `w=(dat$return, dat$assets))` is a syntax error.

And [plyr](http://cran.r-project.org/package=plyr) makes this a little easier:

```
> set.seed(42)   # fix seed so that you get the same results
> dat <- data.frame(assetclass=sample(LETTERS[1:5], 20, replace=TRUE), 
+                   return=rnorm(20), assets=1e7+1e7*runif(20))
> library(plyr)
> ddply(dat, .(assetclass),   # so by asset class invoke following function
+       function(x) data.frame(wret=weighted.mean(x$return, x$assets)))
  assetclass     wret
1          A -2.27292
2          B -0.19969
3          C  0.46448
4          D -0.71354
5          E  0.55354
>
```

Comment: It works like a charm. The first time I tried it, I replaced x in the function with dat (returning the same number for each asset class). 

Any idea why this won't work with the aggregate command?

Comment: It seems `aggregate` aggregates every column wheres you desire computation over two columns.  I think a while ago I use `doBy` or something like it -- but hey, `plyr` makes it easier and has other bells and whistles.

Comment: I *knew* this would happen ;-)  Thanks for waving the cluebat.

Answer (score 11):

A `data.table` solution, will be faster than `plyr`

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(dat)
DT[,list(wret = weighted.mean(return,assets)),by=assetclass]
##    assetclass        wret
## 1:          A -0.05445455
## 2:          E -0.56614312
## 3:          D -0.43007547
## 4:          B  0.69799701
## 5:          C  0.08850954
```

Comment: I've been meaning to look at data.table for some time now. With growing databases I guess it's about time. Appreciate the pointer!

Answer (score 8):

This is also easily done with aggregate. It helps to remember alternate equations for a weighted mean.

```
rw <- dat$return * dat$assets
dat1 <- aggregate(rw ~ assetclass, data = dat, sum)
datw <- aggregate(assets ~ assetclass, data = dat, sum)
dat1$weighted.return <- dat1$rw / datw$assets
```

Comment: wait a second, this doesn't make sense. You're essentially dividing the mean by the mean number of samples. Weighted mean is the *sum* of weighted values divided by the *sum* of weights

Comment: There's a variety of ways to do weights and in this case it is the number of samples so it's correct. There is more than one equation for weighting. Run it on Dirk's data.

Comment: The use of `mean()` confused me here. It could be `sum()`; using `mean()` implies that we're dividing the numerator and denominator by `nlevels(assetclass)` (for very large datasets the mean might be numerically more stable though)

Comment: Yes, for the two aggregates this could be rewritten using `sum`. It comes out the same because the ratio of two sums over equal lengths equals the ratio of two means (obviously the denominators in the mean are constant). Looking back I'm not even sure why I put mean in there so I've changed it to sums. I might have been looking through a book of weighted mean equations and just selected an alternative that works.

Answer (score 2):

The recently released `collapse` package provides a fast solution to this and similar problems (using weighted median, mode etc.) by providing a full set of [Fast Statistical Functions](https://sebkrantz.github.io/collapse/reference/fast-statistical-functions.html) performing grouped and weighted computations internally in C++:

```
library(collapse)
dat <- data.frame(assetclass = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 20, replace = TRUE), 
                  return = rnorm(20), assets = 1e7+1e7*runif(20))

# Using collap() function with fmean, which supports weights: (by default weights are aggregated using the sum, which is prevented using keep.w = FALSE)
collap(dat, return ~ assetclass, fmean, w = ~ assets, keep.w = FALSE)
##   assetclass     return
## 1          A -0.4667822
## 2          B  0.5417719
## 3          C -0.8810705
## 4          D  0.6301396
## 5          E  0.3101673

# Can also use a dplyr-like workflow: (use keep.w = FALSE to omit sum.assets)
library(magrittr)
dat %>% fgroup_by(assetclass) %>% fmean(assets)
##   assetclass sum.assets     return
## 1          A   80683025 -0.4667822
## 2          B   27411156  0.5417719
## 3          C   22627377 -0.8810705
## 4          D  146355734  0.6301396
## 5          E   25463042  0.3101673

# Or simply a direct computation yielding a vector:
dat %$% fmean(return, assetclass, assets)
##          A          B          C          D          E 
## -0.4667822  0.5417719 -0.8810705  0.6301396  0.3101673
```