# How to summarise data by group with weighted mean?

Tags: r

With

```r
xa=aggregate(x$avg,by=list(x$value),FUN=weighted.mean,w=x$weight)
```

gives me an error

```
Error in weighted.mean.default(X[[1L]], ...) :    'x' and 'w' must
have the same length
```

But

```r
weighted.mean(x$avg,w=x$weight);
```

works fine.

Comment: When you use aggregate, you split your data set in the chunks. So weighted mean is operating on a chunk of data. So the weights should be from this chunk. You however supply the weights from all data. Hence the error message.

Comment: something like this should work: `aggregate(x[,c("avg","weight")],by=list(x$value),FUN=function(d)weighted.mean(d[,1],d[,2]))`

Comment: Could you give this question some fitting tags? (If this language is R, the [tag:r] tag seems right.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Aggregate and Weighted Mean in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367190/aggregate-and-weighted-mean-in-r)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As suggested on an [old R thread](http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/help/03a/7057.html), you can use `by` instead:

```
wt <- c(5,  5,  4,  1)/15
x <- c(3.7,3.3,3.5,2.8)
xx <- data.frame(avg=x, value=gl(2,2), weight=wt)
by(xx, xx$value, function(x) weighted.mean(x$avg, x$weight))
```

Answer (score 5):

This being a 'million ways to skin a cat' question, here's a `plyr` solution (using @chl's example data):

```
ddply(xx,.(value),summarise, wm = weighted.mean(avg,weight))
```