# R weigted average using ddply apply

Tags: r, plyr, apply

Using the following set of data, I am trying to calculate the weighted average of columns `Val1` and `Val2`, for each "Category" using the weights for column `Wt`.

Data:

```
Category,Details,Wt,Val1,Val2
A,Apple,8,3.0,12
A,Apple Gala,30,4.3,8
B,Banana,9,5.7,4
B,Banana Ripe,12,7.3,0
B,Banana Green,16,9.0,-4
C,Cantaloupe,4,10.9,-8
C,Carrot,86,13.0,-12
C,Cane,92,15.3,-16
```

Hoping to accomplish this through this..

```
ddply (data, .(Category), summarize, function (y) {
apply(y[,4:5],2,function(x)  sum (x*Wt/sum(Wt))}
)
```

Actual data set is much larger.

Comment: Did that work or not? You could also do `library(dplyr) ; df %>% group_by(Category) %>% summarise_each(funs(sum(.*Wt/sum(Wt))), Val1:Val2)`

Comment: Wonder if we close with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7148598/how-to-summarise-data-by-group-with-weighted-mean

Comment: Yes please close this.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `apply` inside `ddply` (well, not if you're using `summarize`, which expects you to define individual new columns).

```
ddply(data, .(Category), summarize,
      m1 = weighted.mean(Val1, Wt),
      m2 = weighted.mean(Val2, Wt))
```

If you're worried about efficiency, though, you should upgrade to `dplyr`. The syntax is very similar in this case:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% group_by(Category) %>%
    summarize(
      m1 = weighted.mean(Val1, Wt),
      m2 = weighted.mean(Val2, Wt)
    )
```

Or, if you have more columns you can use David Arenburg's comment to make it scale up.

Comment: Thank you both. This does it for me. I am using Gregor's solution for now.