# Apply Analytical weights to time series data

Tags: r, time-series, stata

I'd like to apply analytical weights to some time series data, but am not sure how to do this in R.  I'm transcribing some `Stata` code and the code uses `collapse` and `[aweight='weightVar']`.

Stata Code

```
collapse temp [aweight='weightVar], by(year);
```

How can I apply analytical weights to data use `croparea` below as the weighting variable to `temp` for each id of each year?

**Sample data**

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), year = c(1900, 
1900, 1900, 1900, 1901, 1901, 1901, 1901), month = c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), temp = c(51.8928991815029, 52.8768994596968, 
70.0998976356871, 62.2724802472936, 51.8928991815029, 52.8768994596968, 
70.0998976356871, 62.2724802472936), croparea = c(50, 50, 50, 
50, 30, 30, 30, 30)), .Names = c("id", "year", "month", "temp", 
"croparea"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")

  id year month     temp croparea
1  1 1900     1 51.89290       50
2  1 1900     2 52.87690       50
3  1 1900     3 70.09990       50
4  1 1900     4 62.27248       50
5  2 1901     1 51.89290       30
6  2 1901     2 52.87690       30
7  2 1901     3 70.09990       30
8  2 1901     4 62.27248       30
```

Comment: Start with the cookbook for summarization here: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Summarizing_data/

Comment: Can you clearly state the objective?  The default func for `collapse` is `mean`; do you want a mean of temps weighted by croparea, grouped by year?

Comment: @patrickmdnet Yes, that is what I'm after, but for each id.  I think I need a larger dataset.

Comment: @patrickmdnet I've updated the data to include months so the mean will work better for each year of each id

Comment: Just a detail, but single quotes as you include them in your Stata code would be illegal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for including sample data!  That makes things much easier.

[Stata `collapse`](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?collapse) is similar to the [R functions `aggregate` or `ddply`](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Summarizing_data/). It looks like you want a weighted (by `croparea`) mean of `temp` grouped by `id`.

[For weighted means in R see this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367190/aggregate-and-weighted-mean-in-r); I'll take the top solution and apply it to your data:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, .(id), function(x) data.frame(wtempmean=weighted.mean(x$temp, x$croparea)))

  id wtempmean
1  1  59.28554
2  2  59.28554
```

Comment: Thanks. This looks good. Are there other functions in r for weighting like this ?  I was not aware of weighted mean

Comment: Is it possible to use `dplyr` instead?  Not sure how to implement this