# Error using weighted.mean in dcast.data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am experimenting with `dcast.data.table` for `weighted.mean`. However it throws an error for this function.

```
library(data.table)
dat = data.table(
  x = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3), 
  y = c(4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6), 
  z = c(7:24), 
  w = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7)
  )
dcast.data.table(
  dat,
  x~y,
  fun.aggregate = weighted.mean, w = 'w',
  value.var= 'z'
)

# Error in weighted.mean.default(z, w = "w") : 
#   'x' and 'w' must have the same length
```

There are workarounds that suggest to use either [`dplyr`](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help//2015-July/430617.html) or [`data.table[]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367190/aggregate-and-weighted-mean-in-r) but none explain why `dcast` doesn't work.

As @Frank points out, the `fun.aggregate` argument of `dcast` can only take functions whose output is a single value. However, I don't think that this is the issue with `weighted.mean`. If I don't specify weights it get valid answer

```
dcast.data.table(
  dat,
  x~y,
  fun.aggregate = weighted.mean, 
  value.var= 'z'
  # ,w = 'w'
)
```

This is also demonstrated with `quantile` function which gives me a valid answer when the result for each function is a single value (i.e. by specifying single value for `probs`)

```
dcast.data.table(
  dat,
  x~y,
  fun.aggregate = quantile, 
  value.var= 'z',
  probs = c(0.25)
)
```

However when it is written to output a vector for each combination, I get an error commensurate with the limitation of `fun.aggregate` but different from the error I get with using `weighted.mean`

```
dcast.data.table(
  dt,
  x~y,
  fun.aggregate = quantile, 
  value.var= 'z',
  probs = c(0.25,0.75)
)
# Error: Aggregating function(s) should take vector inputs and return a single value (length=1). However, function(s) returns length!=1. This value will have to be used to fill any missing combinations, and therefore must be length=1. Either override by setting the 'fill' argument explicitly or modify your function to handle this case appropriately.
```

It seems that `dcast` doesn't split up the `w` argument for each function and passes the entire vector to `weighted.mean` function. I want to understand what internally prevents this function from doing this.

Comment: To me, it is quite natural that a function will only have the functionality it says it will have and was designed to have. Arun modified `dcast` based on the function found in reshape2.

Comment: From `?dcast`: "The aggregating function should take a vector as input and return a single value (or a list of length one) as output." As a workaround, apply the function first: `dat[, weighted.mean(z,w), by=.(x,y)][, dcast(.SD, x~y)]` (I'm converting my answer to comment.) I don't think there is a way to meaningfully answer your question. You can read the code of the function very easily (type `dcast.data.table`) if that's what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Wath about this?

```
dat = data.frame(x = c(1,1,2,2),
y = c(4,4,5,5),
z = c(1,2,3,4),
w = c(1,2,1,2))

weighted.sum
reshape2::dcast(data =  dat, formula=x~y, 
fun.aggregate = function(x){mean(x*dat$w)*length(x)},
value.var= c('z'))

#weighted.mean
reshape2::dcast(data =  dat, formula=x~y, 
fun.aggregate = function(x){mean(x*dat$w)}, 
value.var= c('z'))
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: I suggest framing this answer in a way that isn't a question. Either confirm the answer is correct or be more confident in your answer. :)