# Joining data with weighted averages and multiple weights in R

Tags: r, weighted-average

So I  had [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49041280/getting-a-weighted-average-in-r-when-joining-two-tables) but the scope got a little larger/more complicated.

Basically I want to combine two tables and calculate the weighted average for any duplicate IDs. The problem is I will have multiple sets of columns that will need to use different weights. Here's my two datasets (RMS1 and RMS2) and the desired outcome (Joined):

```
RMS1:
id,freq1,sev1,count1,freq2,sev2,count2
111 0    2    50     1     2    25
222 1    3    75     2     4    50

RMS2:               
id,freq1,sev1,count1,freq2,sev2,count2
222 2    4    25     6     6    200
333 4    5    60     3     2    20

Joined:                         
id  freq1   sev1    freq2   sev2        
111 0       2       1       2       
222 1.25*   3.25*   5**     5.5**       
333 4       5       3       2
```

So the * values are weighted averages based on count1, but the ** values are weighted averages based on count2 (at least they should be, I tried to do the math quickly). My entire dataset has 13 groups that use separate counts for weights. I have this code but obviously it needs to be expanded to take in multiple weights:

```
Joined <- bind_rows(RMS1, RMS2) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(-count1), funs(weighted.mean(., count1))) %>%
  as.data.frame()
```

Being new to R I have no idea where to even start. I found a [possibly related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42993956/aggregate-and-weighted-mean-for-multiple-columns-in-r), but it's going over my head. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say you have 13 groups, what do you mean? Do you mean that there is a count3, count4, etc... or that there is a RMS3, RMS4, etc... or that there is an id 333, 444, 555 etc...

Comment: I mean there is freq 1-13, sev1-13, and count 1-13

Answer (score 1):

A solution using [tidyr](/questions/tagged/tidyr) and [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr). The idea is to convert the data frame, conduct the calculation, and transform back to the original format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

Joined <- bind_rows(RMS1, RMS2) %>%
  mutate(rowid = 1:n()) %>%
  gather(Column, Value, -id, -rowid) %>%
  extract(Column, into = c("Type", "Number"), 
          regex = "([A-Za-z]*)([0-9]*)", convert = TRUE) %>%
  spread(Type, Value) %>%
  group_by(id, Number) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(-rowid, -count), funs(weighted.mean(., count))) %>%
  gather(Type, Value, -id, -Number) %>%
  unite(Column, Type, Number, sep = "") %>%
  spread(Column, Value) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  as.data.frame()
Joined
#    id freq1 freq2 sev1 sev2
# 1 111  0.00   1.0 2.00  2.0
# 2 222  1.25   5.2 3.25  5.6
# 3 333  4.00   3.0 5.00  2.0
```

**DATA**

```
RMS1 <- read.table(text = "id freq1 sev1 count1 freq2 sev2 count2
111 0    2    50     1     2    25
222 1    3    75     2     4    50
", header = TRUE)

RMS2 <- read.table(text = "id freq1 sev1 count1 freq2 sev2 count2
222 2    4    25     6     6    200
                   333 4    5    60     3     2    20
                   ", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Part of what makes this answer great is that it works on any number of columns freq1, freq2, freq3, etc so long as the naming scheme is consistent.

Comment: @Brandon Thanks. Yes. I want the answer to be able to handle multiple groups without specifying column names or numbers.

Answer (score 0):

**1) dplyr** `rbind` the two input data frames together and then grouping by `id` perform a
weighted mean on each required column:

```
library(dplyr)

RMS1 %>%
     rbind(RMS2) %>%
     group_by(id) %>%
     summarize(freq1 = weighted.mean(freq1, count1),
               sev1 = weighted.mean(sev1, count1),
               freq2 = weighted.mean(freq2, count2),
               sev2 = weighted.mean(sev2, count2)) %>%
     ungroup
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
     id freq1  sev1 freq2  sev2
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   111  0     2.00  1.00  2.00
2   222  1.25  3.25  5.20  5.60
3   333  4.00  5.00  3.00  2.00
```

**2) sqldf** An alternative using sql is:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select id, 
              sum(count1 * freq1 + 0.0) / sum(count1) freq1,
              sum(count1 * sev1 + 0.0)  / sum(count1) sev1,
              sum(count2 * freq2 + 0.0) / sum(count2) freq2,
              sum(count2 * sev2 + 0.0)  / sum(count2) sev2
       from (select * from RMS1 union select * from RMS2)
       group by id", method = "raw")
```

giving:

```
   id freq1 sev1 freq2 sev2
1 111  0.00 2.00   1.0  2.0
2 222  1.25 3.25   5.2  5.6
3 333  4.00 5.00   3.0  2.0
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form is:

```
Lines1 <- "
id freq1 sev1 count1 freq2 sev2 count2
111 0    2    50     1     2    25
222 1    3    75     2     4    50"
RMS1 <- read.table(text = Lines1, header = TRUE)

Lines2 <- "
id freq1 sev1 count1 freq2 sev2 count2
222 2    4    25     6     6    200
333 4    5    60     3     2    20"
RMS2 <- read.table(text = Lines2, header = TRUE)75 + 25)
```