# Vectorize weighted arithmetics across a matrix

Tags: r, weighted

I was wondering if there is any way to vectorize the weighted arithmetics across matrices. e.g. for calculating the weighted mean of `values` below given `weights`:

```
set.seed(12321)
values = matrix(sample(10:40, 6, replace = TRUE), ncol = 2)
weights = matrix(sample(1:5, 6, replace = TRUE), ncol = 2)
```

We can do:

```
w.mean = numeric()

for (i in 1:dim(values)[1]){
  w.mean[i] = stats::weighted.mean(x=values[i,], w =  weights[i,])
}
```

But it is not fast for large matrices. I was wondering if there is a completely vectorized way using `apply` family or `aggregate` or similar.

Comment: To convert your code from `for` to `sapply`, you could do `sapply(1:nrow(values), function(i) weighted.mean(values[i, ], weights[i, ]))` but I am not sure if that is efficient than a `for` loop.

Comment: A `for` loop is probably as fast as you can get. You could try `matrixstats::weightedMean` which will be faster. What constitutes a 'large' matrix (i.e. many columns, many rows, both)?

Comment: maybe `apply(abind::abind(values, weights, along = 3), 1, function(x) weighted.mean(x[,1], x[,2]))`

Answer (score 2):

you can try grouping your values and weights in one data.frame

```
value_weight <- data.frame(group = rep(1:2, each = 3), 
                           value = sample(10:40, 6, replace = TRUE), 
                           weight = sample(1:5, 6, replace = TRUE))
```

and then using the `plyr` library

```
ddply(value_weight, .(group), # split the data frame according to group
      function(x) data.frame(wret = weighted.mean(x$value, x$weight)))
```

more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367190/aggregate-and-weighted-mean-in-r)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, everyone. Really insightful answers. I tested them and `sapply` turned out to be fast, and after that `abind`. However, in my original dataset I had groupings which I had summarized over groups using `dcast`. However, after I saw the suggestion for `ddply` I went back to it. I realized using `data.table::data.table` makes it orders of magnitude faster:

```
n = 1000
DT = data.table(id = sample(LETTERS[1:10], size = n, replace = TRUE),
                value = sample(seq(20,30), size = n, replace = TRUE),
                weight = sample(seq(1,5), size = n, replace = TRUE))

wtd_var = DT[,lapply(.SD,function(x)(weightedVar(as.numeric(x),w=weight))),by=id,.SDcols='value']
wtd_var
```

`data.table` rocks, indeed!